# How can I dev locally with GCP Cloud Run without an IDE

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-run, cloud-run-emulator

Google has a Cloud Run Emulator but the only documentation I can find binds it tightly to an IDE, mostly seems to be VSCode.  It seems like a strange design decision and I don't want my whole team to need to use VSCode to test this.

https://cloud.google.com/code/docs/vscode/develop-service

Why did Google decide to have an IDE dependency for their emulator?

How do I get around this dependency?

Comment: It's likely I accept that I don't actually need to test through the emulator.  It's still a strange move and I'm not a fan.  If there's a good reason I'd like to know it.

Answer (score 2):

The IDE is the preferred place for developer to create their code. VS Code and IntelliJ are the most popular and Google Cloud has focused its effort on them.

However, it's not mandatory to have an IDE to run a Cloud Run container on a K3S cluster. The command `gcloud beta code dev`, documentation [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/beta/code/dev), allow you to achieve the same thing locally.

You have less visual functionalities and possibilities, but you can script your deployment, even your tests, locally with that command.